# Could not get WSDL contract error when deploying web service in WildFly

Tags: java, web-services, wildfly

I am trying to deploy my web service in WildFly server, but I am getting following exception:

```
6:44:06,265 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."MyService.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."MyService.war".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "MyService.war"
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)Caused by: org.jboss.wsf.spi.WSFException: JBWS024109: Could not get WSDL contract for endpoint com.sun.xml.ws.tx.coord.v11.endpoint.RegistrationPortImpl at /wsdls/wsc11/wstx-wscoor-1.1-wsdl-200702.wsdl
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.metadata.MetadataBuilder.getWsdlLocationURL(MetadataBuilder.java:283)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.metadata.MetadataBuilder.build(MetadataBuilder.java:90)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.aspect.DescriptorDeploymentAspect.start(DescriptorDeploymentAspect.java:42)
at org.jboss.as.webservices.deployers.AspectDeploymentProcessor.deploy(AspectDeploymentProcessor.java:73)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
... 5 more
```

How can I resolve the above problem?

Comment: that's the full error I am getting

Comment: It might be a duplicate problem with the libs you provide with your application and the ones in wildfly esp. wstx. You may declare it in maven/gradle/(you name it) as a compile scoped dependency and not as a provided one.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

If someone has the same error, I had compile scope dependency that is below in my `pom.xml`. After I deleted the dependency , the project has deployed and worked nicely.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.metro</groupId>
    <artifactId>webservices-rt</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

see wsdllocation address in `@javax.jws.WebService` annotation. Sometimes there is something wrong with lowercase or uppercase letters. On Windows it might work and on Linux it might not.